# how to update metadata of docx file using apache poi in java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am not getting how to update meta data (title,subject,author etc..) for docx file using apache poi.
I have tried it for a doc file using apache poi:

---

```
     File poiFilesystem = new File(file_path1);

     /* Open the POI filesystem. */
     InputStream is = new FileInputStream(poiFilesystem);
    POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(is);
     is.close();

     /* Read the summary information. */
     DirectoryEntry dir = poifs.getRoot();
     SummaryInformation si;
     try
     {
        DocumentEntry siEntry = (DocumentEntry)
             dir.getEntry(SummaryInformation.DEFAULT_STREAM_NAME);
         DocumentInputStream dis = new DocumentInputStream(siEntry);
         PropertySet ps = new PropertySet(dis);
         dis.close();
         si = new SummaryInformation(ps);
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
     {
         /* There is no summary information yet. We have to create a new
         * one. */
         si = PropertySetFactory.newSummaryInformation();
     }


     si.setAuthor("xzy");
     System.out.println("Author changed to " + si.getAuthor() + ".");
    si.setSubject("mysubject");
    si.setTitle("mytitle");
```

Comment: i didn't get any response to my question ......

Comment: what kind metadata do you want update?

Comment: like author,title etc......

Comment: Hi  Michael Kazarian hope you got my question now ...

Comment: Your question / answers helped me a lot. I just wanted to mention, that, for self-created files like HWPFDocument doc, calling doc.getSummaryInformation() gives you the SummaryInformation direcly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below work with `POI-3.10`. You can set some metadata with [`PackageProperties`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/PackageProperties.html):

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.Nullable;

class SetDOCXMetadata{
  public static void main(String[] args){
      try{
          OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open("metadata.docx");
          PackageProperties pp = opc.getPackageProperties();

          Nullable<String> foo = pp.getLastModifiedByProperty();
          System.out.println(foo.hasValue()?foo.getValue():"empty");
          //Set some properties
          pp.setCreatorProperty("M Kazarian");
          pp.setLastModifiedByProperty("M Kazarian " + System.currentTimeMillis());
          pp.setModifiedProperty(new Nullable<Date>(new Date()));
          pp.setTitleProperty("M Kazarian document");

          opc.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: If you create the document instead of opening it: For XWPFDocument and other classes inheriting from POIXMLDocument, getProperties().getCoreProperties() gives you a CoreProperties instance where you can change all these properties as well.